# protobuf - serialization using protobuf-net with inheritance

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Getting "Unexpected sub type" when serializing.

```
var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
var baseType = model.Add(typeof(BaseClass), true, CompatibilityLevel.Level300);
var child = baseType.AddSubType(10, typeof(ChildOfBase));
child.AddSubType(20, typeof(GrandChildToBase));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{                                  
    model.Serialize(stream, grandChildInstance); //ERROR : Unexpected sub type GrandChildToBase
}
```

Getting "Unexpected sub type GrandChildToBase"
Note: Although, I set CompatLevel to 300, it's defaulting to 200.
I am on version 3.0.101

> I don't want to use "ProtoInclude" on the BaseClass. (All my classes are distributed independently via nuget packages and having knowledge of child classes in base class breaks that)

**EDIT 1**
Serialization is working now! (Thanks Marc Gravell)
But, deserialization is not (Getting "Unable to cast object of type BaseClass to GrandChildToBase")..

```
var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
model.DefaultCompatibilityLevel = CompatibilityLevel.Level300;
var baseType = model.Add(typeof(BaseClass));
var childType = model.Add(typeof(ChildOfBase));
model.Add(typeof(GrandChildToBase)); // don't need to capture result of this one

baseType.AddSubType(10, typeof(ChildOfBase));
childType.AddSubType(20, typeof(GrandChildToBase));
byte[] result = null;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    GrandChildToBase grandChildInstance = new();
    model.Serialize(stream, grandChildInstance);
    result = stream.ToArray();
}
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(result))
    {                   
        var payloadObj = Serializer.Deserialize<GrandChildToBase>(stream); ***//ERROR: "Unable to cast object of type BaseClass to GrandChildToBase"***                  
    }
```

**EDIT 2**
Per @Marc Gravell's clarification, I need to use the custom "model" and not the "default" serializer.

Comment: What is the declared *variable* type of `grandChildInstance`? (Not the object/instance type; the variable type)?

Comment: Its of type "grandChildInstance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is that the `AddSubType` API is intended for *chained builder usage*, and effectively returns *the same object you passed in* - or specifically: the result of `AddSubType` is *not* the `MetaType` representing the sub-type; you can see this via:

```cs
var child = baseType.AddSubType(10, typeof(ChildOfBase));
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(child, baseType)); // outputs True
```

This means that when you then do

```cs
child.AddSubType(20, typeof(GrandChildToBase));
```

you're effectively adding `GrandChildToBase` to `BaseClass`, not to `ChildOfBase`.

I will acknowledge that the library should have told you about this clearly in the `.AddSubType(20, typeof(GrandChildToBase))` step! I'll check to see whether we can add an assertion there.

However! To fix the code:

```cs
var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
model.DefaultCompatibilityLevel = CompatibilityLevel.Level300;
var baseType = model.Add(typeof(BaseClass));
var childType = model.Add(typeof(ChildOfBase));
model.Add(typeof(GrandChildToBase)); // don't need to capture result of this one

baseType.AddSubType(10, typeof(ChildOfBase));
childType.AddSubType(20, typeof(GrandChildToBase));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    GrandChildToBase grandChildInstance = new();
    model.Serialize(stream, grandChildInstance); //ERROR : Unexpected sub type GrandChildToBase
}
```

As a side note: the `10` vs `20` - these are not in conflict with each-other, as they are applied (now) at different levels in the hierarchy; they could both be `10` or any other number if you like.

Comment: Thanks for that @Marc Gravell! I am able to serialize. But, running into "deserialization" issues. Modified my original question with "EDIT 1"

Comment: @teeboy re "EDIT 1" - use `model.Deserialize`, not `Serializer.Deserialize` - the latter uses `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`, not your custom model

Comment: Ha! Thank you. That works.. accepting your answer. So, if I use the "deserialization" in a disconnected architecture (like Kafka), I need to build the same "model" on both publisher and subscriber sides.. Sent u coffee!

Comment: any input on Bson vs Protobuf serialize/deserialize from a storage and cpu usage perspective?

Comment: @teeboy awesome, thanks; re protobuf Vs bson - depends on payload, but both are goodish